# Question about adding column to data source and destination in SSIS package

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a data source which is something like

```
select 
patient_id 
from patient_table
```

the destination is a CSV file.

Now I want to add patient_name to both the source and the destination.

I go to the source and I change the query to

```
select 
patient_id,
patient_name 
from patient_table
```

After I add this when I click on columns the patient_name column is not there.

The same thing happens for my destination. I have a flat file destination with the patient_id column so I add the patient_name column to the actual .csv file and that column is not reflected on the flat file connection manager.

The only way that I've been able to get these new columns to show up is to delete the data flow task, connection managers, sources and destinations and to create everything new from scratch.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a simple data flow with an OLE DB source and a flat file destination.  After adding a second column to the OLE DB source I double clicked my flat file destination which opened the *Flat File Destination Editor*.  Clicking UPDATE added the 2nd column to the flat file connection.

[image: Flat File Destination Editor]

Are you using the [latest tooling](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects) available to modify SSIS packages?

Comment: I went to the connection manager. I added the columns to the SQL command. I preview the data and confirm that there are the added columns when I preview the data. 

When I click on the columns there are two sections. The available external columns section which does not have the patient_name column. The section below shows the external column and output column are both missing the patient_name
https://imgur.com/a/izvfAhm

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an SSDT installation handy right now, so I'll do the best I can without screenshots (and working from memory).

In the Source object, after you add the column to the text of your query, click on `Columns`, which you already know. Your new column doesn't show up in the list at the bottom yet, which you also know. Up in the top of that window, there's a grid representation of the result set from the query. Find your new column in that grid and check the box to tell the connector you want that column to enter the data flow.

Now go to the connection manager for the `.csv` file. Add the new column there.

Once it's in the connection manager, now you should be able to map it in the destination object.

There's a possibility that you'll have to click on the arrow or arrows in your data flow task and map the new column in those, too, but it doesn't always happen like that. I haven't taken the time to figure out why that's necessary sometimes and not others, but you'll know right away because the arrows will have red `X`s on them.

And that should get you there.